# Obtaining data from the form with GET data. Django

Tags: python, django, forms

How can I get data from the form using the GET method?

For example, I have this form:

```
class LoansSearchForm(forms.Form):
    balance = forms.IntegerField(label='', required=False)
```

In my view display in the form template this way:

```
def search_results(request):
    form = LoansSearchForm(request.GET)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    word = cd['balance']

    context = {'form': form,
               'test': word,}
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

But i still a error:

```
'LoansSearchForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

When trying to get them this way:

```
word = form['balance']
```

I receive a field with completed data. How to get the data from my the form correctly?

Is my form written correctly? Should I use something like that?
(sorry if my question is trivial, but I found very little information about GET forms)

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = LoansSearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('Hello World')
else:
    form = LoansSearchForm()
```

Comment: there's no difference between what you call a "GET form" or "POST form". You initialise a form with a `data` attribute (`LoansSearchForm(data={...})`) where you pass in a dict or MultiValueDict or QueryDict (which `request.GET` and `request.POST` are). So there's not problem passing in `request.GET`, you're doing it correctly. But like with any Django form, `cleaned_data` property is created when you call `is_valid()` (or `errors`), you can't fetch `cleaned_data` without cleaning the form first.

Comment: `Once you’ve created a Form instance with a set of data and validated it, you can access the clean data via its cleaned_data attribute` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommended: run `form.is_valid()` and then you do `form.cleaned_data`

```
def search_results(request):
    form = LoansSearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        word = cd['balance']
    else:
        word = None

    context = {'form': form,
               'test': word,}
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

> Forms only get a `cleaned_data` attribute when `is_valid()` has been called, and you haven't called it anywhere.

more on cleaned data - [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data)

Comment: "looks like your form has errors" is wrong, remove that sentence from your answer. You cannot access a form's `cleaned_data` regardless of whether the form is valid or not, until you actually call the form's `full_clean()` method either via `is_valid()` or `errors`.

Comment: @dirkgroten oh yes, I forgot about full_clean(). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
def search_results(request):
    form = LoansSearchForm(request.GET)
    cd = form.cleaned_data                       # here <------
    word = cd['balance']

    context = {'form': form,
               'test': word,}
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
```

The problem with your code is that forms are not filled on initialization but when you call `form.is_valid`, if the form is indeed valid, then it populates cleaned_data

You can read more about the related [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-form-class).

Answer (score 0):

I used name=form.data['field_name'], think it answers your answer of obtaining form values on submit.